# Printing reports without showing filters

Tags: reports

Is it possible to print reports without the list of filters used displayed at the top?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Title and Format tab, insert this in the Report Header just before the closing `</head>` tag near the bottom:

`<style type="text/css">table.statistics-table { display: none; }</style>`

Comment: Thank you so much!